# What is the difference between a 'materials and methods' section and an 'experimental procedure' section?

Tags: thesis, homework, literature

What is the difference between 'material and methods' section and 'experimental procedure' section in a scientific article or report or assignment? Does they differ at all?

Elaboration :

If I'm told to write a scientific article or assignment whose outline contains a 'materials and methods' section and 'experimental procedure' section; should I write 2 separate sections for them? Or should I use a single section (any one of the 2) Because i perceive like introducing both section would make much of the part of assignment redundant because I perceive like 'method' and 'procedure' as very much same thing (don't know if I'm wrong).

Comment: If this is an assignment, then ask your professor for clarification.

Comment: @Buffy initially it is an assignment but if the professor thinks it is not too bad the they may include it as a publication.

Comment: But what are the general conventions for these 2 terms? Are they same?

Comment: The differences between the sections can even be different between journals. Have you read any articles for class? Does your professor have a favorite journal s/he has published to? I would try to skim / read some of the articles to find out what the norms are for that community.

Comment: okay thanks @Van i am very new to research based academia and I yet studied papers only to find protocols/methods and concepts. I don't remember the professors' favourite journal.

Comment: The names of sections tend to be arbitrary. Most fields have some variety of "Methods" section, but some call it different names, some fields allow you to name it whatever you want and no one will complain, some fields use sub-sections, some use the term "materials" and "apparatus" interchangably, etc. For publication this is usually one of those things you either use a set template for which is generic to your style/field, or you play around with during late editing phases trying to decide which organization makes the most sense (and fits any page limit).